# Set Maps API key within Google Sheets

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, api-key, custom-function

I have build up some custom function for my Google Spread Sheet e.g `DRIVINGTIME("orgin"; "destination")`. The function runs

```
var l_directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setOrigin( origin )
  .setDestination( destination )
  .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
  .getDirections();
```

but the request daily limit is reached. How can I add my API key to this call? I prefer a script property with the API key, but on the [`directionFinder` documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/direction-finder), I don't find a method to add my API key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Supply API key to avoid Hit Limit error from Maps Service in Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703364/supply-api-key-to-avoid-hit-limit-error-from-maps-service-in-apps-script)

Comment: While the linked question is concerned with distance, my answer demonstrates how to use script properties to store the necessary Maps authentication criteria and apply them when required.

Comment: it looks like Maps.setAuthentication is only for Premium Plan customers, is there any for Standard Plan customers?