# Authenticate with API key in spreadsheet

Tags: google-maps, authentication, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have code in a Google Sheets that uses the Google Maps API to calculate distance between two locations.
I have a Google API key but don't know how to insert it into my code to authenticate. I do not have a client ID.
Can anybody help?

```
function DISTANCE(origin, destination) {
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .getDirections();
  return directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/maps#setAuthentication(String,String)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703364