# Can't get my Google API to connect properly for mapping project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-maps-api-3, maps, zipcode

I need to calculate the google maps derived distance between around 72,000 pairs of zip codes. I found a function online for google sheets which will do this, but I of course ran out of calls well before getting through the 72,000. So I set up billing within google maps api and now have an API key along with a ClientID. But I still can't get this to work. See below where "I tried adding this" based on what I've been able to find elsewhere.

```
function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address,return_type) {
  // I tried adding this:  var key = "";
  // I tried adding this: var clientID = "YourClientIDHERE.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  // I tried adding this: maps.setauthentication(clientID,key);

  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();

  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  Utilities.sleep(6000);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

  switch(return_type){
    case "miles":
      return meters * 0.000621371;
      break;
    case "minutes":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to minutes and return
        return duration / 60;
      break;
    case "hours":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to hours and return
        return duration / 60 / 60;
      break;      
    case "kilometers":
      return meters / 1000;
      break;
    default:
      return "Error: Wrong Unit Type";
   }

}
```

Comment: I think this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948812/set-maps-api-key-in-script-editor

Answer (score 0):

The function works fine.  I tested it between my current home and my childhood home and got 1212 miles.  With Google Maps it was 1212 Miles.  So pretty close I'd say.

Comment: Yes I know the function works fine, but I'm trying to get my API connection to work properly so I can run it 72,000 times.